# method for linked list class even number sub list

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, nodes

I have to create my own linked list class, with a bunch of methods in them, like add, delete, sort, print, etc, and Ive done all the methods but one. I need to create a method with this task, or this is what is listed on the guidelines for the assignment:

Generate a sub-list that contains all the even numbers in the current list. 
This list should be returned and the contents should be displayed 
(to the screen), one number per line.

I dont really understand how to do this. so basically the user is prompted to create a linked list of random numbers, and the user specifies how many. so if he says 10. then the linked list will generate 10 listnodes with random numbers on them, and I want to create another linked list of just even numbers, and print them to the screen one number per line. any suggestions, pseudocode, or if you just know it, feel free to let me know! this method has stumped me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are misunderstanding the question. You just need to traverse the list and keep printing the even numbers as you encounter them. Also, start with a new linked list, and whenever you encounter a node with an even number, add it to the new linked list. By the time you reach the end, you'd have already printed all the even nos, you just have to return the new linked list that you have.

If you are still having trouble with this, post your code..